# Java: Looping a sound when it's finished playing

Tags: java, audio

I have a program containing a Title Screen.In said Title Screen, I want music to be looped. I have a music file already created and it is about 10 seconds long. I want it to keep repeating when it finishes but I don't know how to check if it has finished or how to loop it.

Here is my sound class:

```
public class Sound {

    public static final Sound cash = new Sound("/cash.wav");
    public static final Sound snap = new Sound("/snap.wav");
    public static final Sound disarm = new Sound("/disarm.wav");
    public static final Sound tp = new Sound("/tp.wav");
    public static final Sound select = new Sound("/selectBTN.wav");
    public static final Sound scroll = new Sound("/btn.wav");
    public static final Sound fire = new Sound("/fire2.wav");

    public static final Sound titlemusic = new Sound("/music/TitleMusic.wav");

    private AudioClip c;

    public Sound(String filename) {
        try {
            c = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource(filename));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        try {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    if (!title.mute) {

                        c.play();


                    }
                }
            }.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I tell it to play a sound like this when I want to play it:

```
        Sound.titlemusic.play();
```

Comment: What exactly is your question / problem?

Comment: I don't know how to loop it

Comment: Have you tried using `AudioClip`'s `loop` method?

Comment: but how do I check if it has finished playing